# Hibernate fetch data from tables OneToMany How to do that?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to fetch data into a table jsp page 
First Class Zebra

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "zebra")
    private List<Niveau2> niveau2;
```

Second Class Niveau2

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idzebra")
    private Zebra zebra;
```

For fetching data

```
 <c:forEach items="${ni2s }" var="niveau2">
<tr class="odd gradeX">
<td class="center">${niveau2.zebra.pole }</td>
<td class="center">${niveau2.zebra.zone }</td>
<td class="center">${niveau2.zebra.ligne }</td>
```

this is working but i want to do the opposite

```
<td class="center">${zebra.niveau2.idniv2 }</td>
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your `@OneToMany` relationship like this.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "zebra")
```